# How to execute common code with multiple condition

Tags: php, url, if-statement

I am trying to give two or more condition and condition-wise I am try to store a different different values with same variable name and by using that variable I should perform remaining operation (this source code is common for each condition).

Means from two or more condition only one condition is true at a time then store values in variable(Variable values may different but the variable name is same).

Then I execute remaining code by using this variable value.

For example see below code to understand what actually I want.

```
<?php
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$a="http://www.abcd.com";
$b="http://www.abcd.com?pm";
$c="http://www.abcd.com?cm";

if($url==$a)
{
    $deeplink=1234;
    $mer="hello";
}
if($url==$b)
{
    $deeplink=9090;
    $mer="hru";
}
if($url==$c)
{
    $deeplink="xyz";
    $mer="hru";
}
Remaining code by using $deeplink and $mer variables
(this remainig code is common for all condition but it will take 
$deeplink and $mer value at a time and execute this code)
?>
```

Comment: What about using `switch` ?

Comment: Is it possible by using switch case can you just explain above scenario using switch

Comment: I got my output thanks for your co-operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for documentation about php `switch` - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

In two words in switch `$url` is compared with each `case` value like  `$url == "http://www.abcd.com"` and triggering `case` block content till `break;`

```
switch ($url) {
    case "http://www.abcd.com":
        $deeplink=1234;
        $mer="hello";
    break;
    case "http://www.abcd.com":
        $deeplink=9090;
        $mer="hru";
    break;
    /*... other conditions if you need more */
    default: // <- if no match found your switch will come to default case
        $deeplink=false;
        $mer="";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can and should use [switch](http://php.net/manual/ro/control-structures.switch.php) statement when you want to compare one variable (or expression) with many different values.

```
<?php
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$a="http://www.abcd.com";
$b="http://www.abcd.com?pm";
$c="http://www.abcd.com?cm";

switch($url){
  case $a:
    $deeplink=1234;
    $mer="hello";
    break;
  case $b:
    $deeplink=9090;
    $mer="hru";
    break;
  case $c:
    $deeplink="xyz";
    $mer="hru";
    break;       
}

Remaining code by using $deeplink and $mer variables
(this remainig code is common for all condition but it will take 
$deeplink and $mer value at a time and execute this code)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go for `elseif` statement.

Like so:

```
if($url==$a)
{
    $deeplink=1234;
    $mer="hello";
}
elseif($url==$b)
{
    $deeplink=9090;
    $mer="hru";
}
elseif($url==$c)
{
    $deeplink="xyz";
    $mer="hru";
}
```

Remaining code by using $deeplink and $mer variables (this remaining code is common for all condition but it will take `$deeplink` and `$mer` value at a time and execute this code).

[PHP elseif statement manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)